# Is there a way to run a single unit test function instead of the whole test class in Python?

Tags: python, eclipse, testing, pydev

I am using eclipse and am trying to run only 1 of the test functions in my unit test class instead of all the functions every time. How would I do this? This is what my test class looks like:

```
import unittest
from X import func1
from X import func2

class XTest(unittest.TestCase):


    def test_firstTest(self):
        assertEqual(func1(), "hello")

    def test_secondTest(self):
        assertEqual(func2(), "bye")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

In eclipse, if I run this as a python unit test, both the test functions run. I want to only run one of the functions. For example, only test_firsttest. Sorry, if this is very trivial, I am new to Python.

Answer (score 0):

To run a single unittest from the commandline use:

> The unittest module can be used from the command line to run tests from modules, classes or even individual test methods:

```
python -m unittest test_module1 test_module2
python -m unittest test_module.TestClass
python -m unittest test_module.TestClass.test_method
```

Read more @ [unittest](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface)

In your case, something like this:

```
$ python -m unittest test_module.XTest.test_firstTest
```